# Can I run two same devices separately on Arduino on I2C?

Tags: arduino, i2c, lcd

My problem is: I have Arduino Mega and two 16x2 LCD displays with I2C converter on each and I want to show two different texts on them. Is it possible and if it is, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you know how to control one I2C module. Multiple devices on the same lines use a hardware address to tell them apart.

Usually your module will have a way to change the address or will have a randomly coded address. If it is the former, documentation is your friend. If it is the latter then use the I2C address scanner at: http://arduino.cc/playground/Main/I2cScanner and find the addresses.

If you need further description on what to do I will need the type of module you are using so we can look at a data sheet together.

Answer (score 0):

Most I2C port extenders used in these converters have 3 "legs" for ID control (A0,A1,A2) with these you can choose from 8 different addresses, so you can have 8 of a kind modules on the same bus.

most of them have unsoldered connections on the pcb.

see image for example.
http://www.elecrow.com/images/s/201405/13995491573.jpg